# Spring Log4j RollingFileAppender change folder

Tags: spring, log4j, compression, rollingfileappender

my log was running correctly with RollingFileAppender but I need compress generated files and move to folder "${app.log}\Backup". Attach log4j properties:

```
log4j.appender.appDebug=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.appDebug.file=${app.log}\\app_exe.log
log4j.appender.appDebug.MaxFileSize=100MB
log4j.appender.appDebug.maxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.appDebug.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.appDebug.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} {%-15.15t} [%-5p] %m %n
log4j.appender.appDebug.Threshold = DEBUG
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add below :

```
log4j.appender.appDebug.rollingPolicy=org.apache.log4j.rolling.FixedWindowRollingPolicy
log4j.appender.appDebug.rollingPolicy.maxIndex=5
log4j.appender.appDebug.triggeringPolicy=org.apache.log4j.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy
log4j.appender.appDebug.triggeringPolicy.MaxFileSize=10000
```

Comment: I'm using log4j-1.2.16 but when application runs shows:


`log4j:WARN No such property [rollingPolicy] in org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppen
der.
log4j:WARN No such property [triggeringPolicy] in org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAp
pender.`

Comment: Try on  log4j-1.2.17

Comment: Its there in apache-log4j-extras-1.2.17